# How does S-Class heroes' power compare to threat levels?

Tags: one-punch-man

In *One Punch Man*, there are classes for heroes, and threat levels for monsters/villains. How does S-Class heroes' power compare to threat levels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be answered from the information in the bonus chapter, *Threat Level*, in **Volume 15**.

The threat level and hero rank comparison shown in the chapter are:

- Wolf Level - needs 3 Class-C heroes or 1 Class-B hero
- Tiger Level - needs 5 Class-B heroes or 1 Class-A hero
- Demon Level - needs 10 Class-A heroes or 1 Class-S hero

Disaster or threat levels above demon (dragon and god) were never compared but based on the events in the manga, this might require multiple Class-S heroes, depending on the ability or capability of both the monster and the hero facing it.

---

There are different threat levels decided upon by the Hero Association. The decision on the threat level depends on

> factors such as strength, aggressiveness, and the estimated difficulty in defeating [the monster].

It was also noted in the same chapter that

> hero ranks are an imperfect representation of combat ability due to inconsistent factors like battleground conditions and monster compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This class of heroes was originally created to include characters who can defeat **Demon level threats** on their own. That said, some of the **high ranked S class heroes such as Tatsumaki** are capable of fighting **Dragon level Threats** by themselves or with the assistance of other S class heroes. Another good example is **Elder Centipede who is a Dragon Level threat** and was defeated by **Blast, the first ranked S class hero**.

Comment: Add some chapter to support your answer.